# How do I make a button change on keypress without focusing it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a program in which when you hit a key it will show a button in a keyboard like row on screen so I'm trying to make the buttons change color while pressed and go back to normal when released without focusing the button, is there a way in which I can make this?

I've been looking at a lot of tutorials and code snippets but none of them seems to work in my case.

the reason why I don't want to focus the buttons is because I have a text box in which written text is shown and changing the focus would just be a bother because you would have to click in it every time you want to write a character.

Comment: Either handle the key inside the textbox (therefore keeping focus to textbox) or record the element focused before (in this case textbox) and reset the focus back after some button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Force the focus back to the `TextBox`.

Example:

```
button1.Click += (sender, args) => 
{
    // where "this" is a Form, if you are inside another control,
    // try "ParentForm" (works for Panel)
    this.ActiveControl = textBox1;
};
```

About the colors, I usually do with `Label`, but you can change the following to `Button`

```
internal class LabelButton : Label
{
    public Color MouseOverColor {get; set;} = Color.Red;
    public Color MouseDownColor {get; set;} = Color.Green;
    public Color NormalColor {get; set;} = Color.Blue;

    public LabelButton() {
        MouseDown  += (sender, args) => BackColor = MouseDownColor;
        MouseUp    += (sender, args) => BackColor = NormalColor;
        MouseEnter += (sender, args) => BackColor = MouseOverColor;
        MouseLeave += (sender, args) => BackColor = NormalColor;
    }
}
```